# Polymorphism in Rust: Canonical way

Tags: rust, polymorphism

What is the canonical way to do the following in Rust?

```
let s: Shape;
if something {
    s = Circle::new();
} else {
    s = Square::new();
}
```

The way that seems most obvious to me:

```
use std::env;

trait Shape {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}

struct Circle {
    rad: f32,
}

impl Circle {
    pub fn new() -> Circle {
        Circle {
            rad: 5.0,
        }
    }
}

impl Shape for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.rad * self.rad * 3.14159
    }
}

struct Square {
    len: f32,
}

impl Square {
    pub fn new() -> Square {
        Square {
            len: 5.0,
        }
    }
}

impl Shape for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.len * self.len
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let s: Shape;
    if args.len() > 1 {
        s = Circle::new();
    } else {
        s = Square::new();
    }
    println!("Area: {}", s.area());
}
```

Results in:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Shape: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:46:9
   |
46 |     let s: Shape;
   |         ^ `Shape` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
```

In general, Circle and Square may indeed have different sizes, so we really **can't** know what size 's' will be at compile time.

This question [Polymorphism in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363369/polymorphism-in-rust) would seem to indicate that you need to write a wrapper struct (called ShapeStruct in this example), which takes a generic and where you break out each function that the trait implements like:

```
struct ShapeStruct<T> {
    shape: T,
}

impl<T: Shape> ShapeStruct<T> {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.shape.area()
    }
}
```

But this would result in a lot of boilerplate - each function that the trait declares would need a break out like 'area' is broken out above. Is there no better way?

Comment: You can use Trait objects for exactly this: `let mut s: Box<Shape>` and then instantiate it with `s = Box::new(Circle::new())` for example